# Display flash, video, photo in slideshow

Tags: 7

I want to build a views slideshow. How can I display several format in this slideshow like flash format, video formats and photos together?

I want to upload a flash file, two photos, and one video to show them in a slideshow. I'm using Drupal 7.14.

Comment: Were you able to create a Slideshow of Videos using Views Slideshow module? (Looking to do same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module can loop through more than just Images.  You can even have it look through rendered nodes or custom content.

By using the Views theme and template features and views slideshow you should be able to mix nearly any content you want.

There is a [video by Bob Christenson](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode42) that gives a very good intro to the Views Slideshow module.  Though it is for D6, most of the content is similar enough to be useful in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

in this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97766/creating-image-slider-in-drupal-7) there is a slideshow of images. by installing [mediaFront](https://drupal.org/project/mediafront) module you can link the thumbnails to a player, in this way by clicking on any of the thumbnails the player will play the video. besides that many slideshow modules have been introduced.