# How to create slideshow having both video and image slides

Tags: 7, files, views

I am using [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module for slideshow banner in my Home page, I  create slides with images but I also want to add **videos** in that slider.

I have installed [video](https://www.drupal.org/project/video) module to create **video** field for slide content type, but I don't know how to call this in slider with the condition auto play on page load?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the Views Slideshow module can just about incorporate videos, but I'm not sure whether or not you need the video module specifically for it, as even though it might include views plugins, it's probably more down to whether or not the slideshow itself is capable of playing videos rather than what the view outputs. These 2 links might be useful for you

[Display flash, video, photo in slideshow](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34409/display-flash-video-photo-in-slideshow)

[HOWTO - Make Video available in Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/node/1061032)